# How can i use primary key with 2 foreign key ? (ınsert statement error)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm getting this error and can't figure that out - hope you can help me.

This is the error I get :

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Recipes_Orders_Recipes". The conflict occurred in database "Food_Management", table "dbo.Recipes", column 'Recipes_ID'.

This is the code that caused this error:

```
private void button2_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Recipes_Orders (Order_ID, Recipe_ID) VALUES (@Order_ID, @Recipe_ID)", con);

        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Recipe_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox2.SelectedValue;

        komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
}
```

My tables related to this error are like this

1. `Orders` (Order_ID (PK), etc etc)
2. `Recipes_Orders` (Recipe_ID (FK), Order_ID (FK), Recipes_Orders_ID (PK))
3. `Recipes` (Recipes_ID (PK), etc etc)

`Recipes_ID` that error mention has two FK because one need to go ingredients and one need to go in orders.

Real problem is it's sometimes work just like I wanted as you can see in the screenshot below I can add recipes (Yemek İsmi) for `order_ID = 1` and 2 but can't add recipes any other orders.

[image: Order_ID 1 and 2 works just fine]

This is what i get from combobox1 and 2 selected values

[image]

Comment: The error means you're trying to insert a value for Recipe_ID into the RecipesOrders table, but the problem is that Recipe_ID doesn't exist in the Recipes table. So if it's a new recipe, you must first insert into the Recipe table, get the created ID for the new row, and then insert a row into RecipesOrders using that ID.

Comment: Yes problem looks like u said but in recipes table recipe_ID identification column  so every new data has recipe_ID and i'm select them through combobox i dont try to add something new in that table.

Comment: Are you sure that you getting the expecting values?

Comment: @spzvtbg yes cause it's works for order_ID 1 and 2 but i didnt work for i create news and error said its from recipe_ID but it doesnt looks like that

Comment: can you debug and show as which values you getting from `comboBox1.SelectedValue;comboBox2.SelectedValue` and the constraints for the keys in your database

Comment: @spzvtbg i'll edit my question now with debugging values

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). And don't develop sloppy coding habits. It is difficult to believe that Order_ID and Recipe_ID are string datatypes in your table - your sample data supports that. More likely they are int and you should define them correctly in your parameter construction code.

Comment: Don't use `SqlDbType.VarChar`... Your keys looked to be integers, so use `SqlDbType.Int`. If they are *really* strings in your database you should fix them to not be

Comment: @SMor as a newbie myself (this is actually my first project) i dont know what to use but addwithvalue actually :)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 i didnt know there was a difference ! i thought varchar will detect what type of my data is so i use them everytime in visual studio i'll look them now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the values in reverced order, exchange the values like below. You don't have a recipe with id 5 according to your example.

```
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox2.SelectedValue;
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Recipe_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
```

Set names for your combo boxes like recipes and orders to avoid further mistakes